# how to print the respective content of the selected menu item from the dropdown using an array using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently able to print the content in the text field by selecting the first menu item of the dropdown but when I select the second menu item, the content in the text field is overwritten with the second one.

Could you please help me with piece of code for the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry, but this question is not very clear. Please try showing what you've tried and point out exactly what you're stuck on. What have you tried so far? Please post the relevant parts of your code where you're getting stuck. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.